# Is this a sufficient proof of $\vdash \neg A \vee A \wedge B \equiv \neg A \vee B$?

Tags: proof-verification, logic

Is this a sufficient proof in the Hilbert Style of $\vdash \neg A \vee (A \wedge B) \equiv \neg A \vee B$?

I'm referencing Distributivity of $\vee$ over $\equiv$ axiom: $A\vee(B\equiv C) \equiv A \vee B \equiv A \vee C$

Proof:

(1) $\neg A \vee ((A \wedge B) \equiv B) \equiv \neg A \vee (A \wedge B) \equiv \neg A \vee B$ (By Distributivity of $\vee$ over $\equiv$ Axiom; 'A-part' is $\neg A$; 'B-Part' is $A\wedge B$; 'C-Part' is $B$)

(2) $\neg A \vee (A \wedge B) \equiv \neg A \vee B \equiv \neg A \vee (A \wedge B) \equiv \neg A \vee B$ (1 + Leibniz; $p \equiv \neg A \vee (A \wedge B) \equiv \neg A \vee B$)

True by previously proven theorem $\vdash A \equiv A$; 'A-part' is $\neg A \vee (A \wedge B) \equiv \neg A \vee B$.

Leibniz (+ Equanimity) application in (2) - 'C-Part' is $p \equiv \neg A \vee (A\wedge B) \equiv \neg A \vee B)$
$$\frac{(\neg A \vee((A\wedge B)\equiv B))\equiv (\neg A  \vee (A\wedge B) \equiv \neg A \vee B)}{C[p:=(\neg A \vee ((A\wedge B)\equiv B))]\equiv C[p:=(\neg A \vee (A\wedge B) \equiv \neg A \vee B)}$$

Comment: I think you need more parentheses to make the structure of your formulas clearer, starting with the one in the title. (And you should describe the goal you're trying to reach _in the body of the question_ too; question bodies ought to be readable without the title).

Comment: Also: if $\equiv$ is a connective that encodes a certain truth function for you, then what does it mean when you string _several_ formulas together with $\equiv$ between them? Does $P\equiv Q\equiv R$ mean $(P\equiv Q)\equiv R$ or perhaps $(P\equiv Q)\land(Q\equiv R)$?

Comment: Your 'proof' is *very* confusing ....  What are (1) and (2)? Lemma's?  What is the "Distributivity of $\lor$ over $\equiv$ Axiom"?  And what is the point of (2)?

Comment: Thanks the original question did not have parenthesis, so I added them based on my interpretation. It seems to match the Distributivity of $\vee$ over $\equiv$ axiom. I added my implementation of Leibniz as well... but how can I make it less confusing?